# Запрет выдачи DHCP-сервером IP-адреса клиенту вне dhcpd.conf

Tags: linux, dhcp

Идея в том, чтобы запретить клиентам получать по DHCP адрес, если этот клиент (хост) не описан в `dhcpd.conf`.

Таковой штатной функциональности в `dhcp` не обнаружил (*возможно, плохо смотрел*), а городить костыли как-то не хочется.

Comment: Давненько не брал шашки в руки, но сдаётся, Вы ошибаетесь. И надо пересмотреть внимательней.

Comment: @Sergey Тыкните носом в шашку, что ж. В смысле, моим носом в шашку dhcp.

Comment: Если все нужные хосты прописаны в conf, а динамический диапазон (subnet с range) не описан, то dhcpd просто не откуда будет выдавать IP и он их не выдаст. С другой стороны такая конфигурация некрасива. Я например держу на интерфейсах два подсети. Одну для зарегенных пользователей и другую для неизвестных (с range). Все запросы на web от неизвестных приходят на сервер который сообщает им, что "ваша машина не зарегестрирована"

Comment: @Mike Кстати, хорошая идея, - просто убрать `range`, я такое не пробовал. Решение не такое красивое, но необходимо, чтобы хост **вообще** не имел доступа в сеть, если его нет в разрешенном списке.

Comment: А хост будет иметь доступ в физическую сеть. Если ему dhcp не даст адрес он возьмет себе адрес из диапазона 169.254 (независимо от вас), причем уникальных и все такие хосты смогут общаться между собой

Comment: Хосты с другой стороны это что-то типа тонких клиентов, которым ничего нельзя, ни консоль, ни чего-либо другого, поэтому с точки зрения "безопасности" этим можно пренебречь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

реализации dhcpd бывают разные. поэтому уточните в документации к вашему dhcpd, поддерживаются ли в нём директивы *deny* и *allow*.

пример можно увидеть, например, [здесь](http://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcpd.conf):

```
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  option routers 10.0.0.254;

 # Unknown clients get this pool.
  pool {
    option domain-name-servers bogus.example.com;
    max-lease-time 300;
    range 10.0.0.200 10.0.0.253;
    allow unknown-clients;
  }

 # Known clients get this pool.
  pool {
    option domain-name-servers ns1.example.com, ns2.example.com;
    max-lease-time 28800;
    range 10.0.0.5 10.0.0.199;
    deny unknown-clients;
  }
}
```

Comment: `deny unknown-clients` - как раз та опция, которую я пропустил в документации. Однако, я не понял, почему тег `сервер` не подходит DHCP-**серверу**

Comment: по поводу меток я придерживаюсь соображения: «может ли существовать „специалист по данной метке“?». по-моему, специалиста по метке «сервер» существовать не может: она **слишком** всеобъемлюща. ну, как, например, метка «компьютер» или «программирование» и т.п.

Comment: Возможно, вы правы. Таким образом, просто не следует позволять существовать таким абстрактным и общим меткам.

Comment: насколько я понимаю, такие метки на [so] принято именовать «мета-метками». поищите информаию по их поводу на [meta].